# Raise exceptions via an event in a class library

Tags: c#, events, exception

Is it a bad practice to give consumers the option of handling exceptions by subscribing to an event that contains the exception? If so, what problems will I likely encounter if I do this?  The code below is an example.

I envision using this pattern with a view model.  The view model would subscribe to the ExceptionRaised event and pass the exception to a logging class.  I don't want to inject the logging class into the StatisticsCalculations class.

```
public class StatisticalCalculations
{
    public event EventHandler<Exception> ExceptionReceived;

    public double GetStandardDeviation(IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
        double standardDeviation = double.NaN;

        try
        {
            double average = values.Average();
            double sum = values.Sum(value => Math.Pow(value - average, 2));
            standardDeviation = Math.Sqrt((sum) / (values.Count() - 1));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionReceived?.Invoke(this, ex);
        }

        return standardDeviation;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Is it a bad practice..."_ -- completely a matter of opinion, and thus not appropriate for Stack Overflow. That said, I fail to see the benefit; it's easy enough for the view model itself to implement some sort of centralized exception reporting, and can do so in a much more appropriate way. Your example catches _all_ exceptions, which is a decidedly bad idea. But at the same time, only the caller really knows what it can reasonably handle correctly vs. what ought to force the process to terminate.

Comment: I disagree with Peter.  There is a benefit.  There is no difference between dumping exception messages into a logger and saving to a file; or adding an exception into a enumerable object.  There is no problem in using your code.  The real issue is finding the root cause of the exception.  Event are asynchronous so just adding the error message to the logger will not give instruction where the error occurred.  So adding the stack trace will give much more info.

Comment: Instead of subscribing to an event, why can't you just handle the exception from calling code? This could be an application-wide wrapper (which is how ASP.NET MVC works out of the box), or caller-specific logic wrapping the call.

Comment: You can't hope for success here. For a start the code won't compile. You don't return in case of an exception. Suppose you fix that and do return something, what do you return? The point of an exception is to indicate that the requesting operation could not be performed. Swallowing exceptions subverts that and leaves you no way to inform the caller that the operation could not be performed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I edited the code so that it will compile. But it is not meant to be production-quality; it is meant to illustrate the essence of my question.  You have answered my question by indicating that it subverts exceptions.

Comment: @AndrewP: The intent was to use the event as a single point of logging the exception rather than having a try-catch block every time a method from this library was called.  Are you saying that I could achieve essentially the same functionality with an application-wide exception handler?

Comment: @blueshift exceptions are typically used for "exceptional" circumstances from which a section of the application either cannot recover itself (calling code has try/catch, or application crashes), or has to take known steps to recover (internal code has try/catch, but usually for specific things). It sounds like what you want to do is to have a notification that an exception has happened, but then continue doing whatever it was you were doing. How will your code know how to "keep doing what it was doing", if you are just throwing an event and moving on?

Answer (score -1):

Using events like this disconnects the exception from the actual method call that you're calling. I think it is better to use an Exception monad for this.

Your class should look like this:

```
public class StatisticalCalculations
{
    public Exceptional<double> GetStandardDeviation(IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
        try
        {
            double standardDeviation = double.NaN;

            //Perform calculation

            return standardDeviation.ToExceptional();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Exceptional<double>(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Your calling function can then unpack the `Exceptional<double>` to see if it got a value or if it got an error.

The classes you need to support this are:

```
public class Exceptional<T>
{
    public bool HasException { get; private set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; private set; }
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public Exceptional(T value)
    {
        HasException = false;
        Value = value;
    }

    public Exceptional(Exception exception)
    {
        HasException = true;
        Exception = exception;
    }

    public Exceptional(Func<T> func)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Value = func();
            this.HasException = false;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            this.Exception = exc;
            this.HasException = true;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.HasException
            ? Exception.GetType().Name
            : (this.Value != null
                ? this.Value.ToString()
                : "null");
    }
}

public static class ExceptionalEx
{
    public static Exceptional<T> ToExceptional<T>(this T value)
    {
        return new Exceptional<T>(value);
    }

    public static Exceptional<T> ToExceptional<T>(this Func<T> func)
    {
        return new Exceptional<T>(func);
    }

    public static Exceptional<U> SelectMany<T, U>(this Exceptional<T> value, Func<T, Exceptional<U>> k)
    {
        return (value.HasException)
            ? new Exceptional<U>(value.Exception)
            : k(value.Value);
    }

    public static Exceptional<V> SelectMany<T, U, V>(this Exceptional<T> value, Func<T, Exceptional<U>> k, Func<T, U, V> m)
    {
        return value.SelectMany(t => k(t).SelectMany(u => new Exceptional<V>(() => m(t, u))));
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this better than allowing the exception to be raised?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - It's better than raising the event to expose the exception because it keeps the call to the method and the resulting exception tightly coupled. Trying to match up the calling with the raised event would be problematic. Further this allows for composition, which raising an event wouldn't allow.

Comment: No. It's better to raise the exception and let the consumer decide if and when to handle it. If the consumer wants to handle this at the top of the call stack they've got to marshal it all the way there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I don't know what you mean. The consumer decide to handle it with a lot more ease with my code than with handling events to send around exceptions. Or are you just saying that the exception should just bubble up like normal rather than using the OP's event-based approach?

Comment: Yes, the exception can bubble up as usual and the consumer decides the appropriate point to handle it. Handcuffing the consumer code to handle it immediately is poor design.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I agree that the best approach is to let the standard exception handling in the framework to this task. Using events to bubble it up is not good. But, using a monad like this is a good design. `Task`, `Nullable`, `IEnumerable`, `IObservable`, `Maybe`, all use this concept of a monad. It's a good design for when it is needed.

Comment: For sure monads have their use, but I don't think this is it. The asker might think he wants to do this, but is surely mistaken.